# I try to fetch random single database from rails by ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using ajax with rails to get single random row I want to display just 10 rows with every request by ajax get one single random and display it, i try something like that, Model.all.sample or Using offset with first but my problem is duplication how can avoid it or how can i set all response to check if I sent it before or not Note: I send all elements was appended as array for backend to check if i send it before and change it but i have wrong 
result

> my code is :- in backend is my function

---

```
    def get_10
        arr =  params['arr']
        if arr.nil?
          @rand_record = Phrase.all.sample
        else
          i = 0
          if i < 10
          @rand_record = Phrase.all.sample
          while(i < arr.length) && (i<10)
            flag = arr[i].include?@rand_record.name
            if flag
              @rand_record = Phrase.all.sample
              i = 0
            elsif flag == false
              return @rand_record 
            end
            i+=1
          end
        end
      end

        respond_to do |format|
          format.js { }
        end
      end
```

> ```
> in my js ajax is :
> ```

```
function myFunction(){
  var arr = []
  var len = $('li').length
  for (let i=0 ; i< len; i++){
   var attr = $('li')[i].childNodes['0'].data
   arr.push(attr)
}

  $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/phrase',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {arr: arr}
      }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      })
}
```

> in template is:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= button_tag 'GetPhrases', type: 'button', onclick:"myFunction()", class: 'btn btn-default' , id:"get" %>
</div>
```

my result is

```
this pharase number 1
this pharase number 5
this pharase number 4
this pharase number 5
this pharase number 8
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCjs2.jpg)
I want to avoid duplication I want to retrive just 10 random single row without duplication

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking here. Can you post some code of what you tried?  What input and what output you expect or want in code and data output?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can I add to this comment my code or delete this and make a new one?

Comment: yes, you can edit your question and use the code formatting

Comment: I edit now my code I hope it's clear for you sorry if I have any grammaer mistakes I hope You can help me

Comment: Still confused. Which "duplication" do you want to avoid?

Comment: I solve it i will delete this question and i will ask something new thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with sample on the active record relation, instead do:

```
Model.where(id: Model.all.pluck(:id).sample(10))
```

This will just pluck all the IDs and sample 10 of them and then select records with those random 10 ids.